# MVC Radiobutton from ViewBag

Tags: model-view-controller, viewbag

I have a problem passing data from radiobutton to model.

This is in my Controller:

```
ViewBag.allProjectAreas = db.ProjectAreas.ToList();
```

This is in my View:

```
@foreach (var a in ViewBag.allProjectAreas)
        {                     
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ProjectAreaID, a.ProjectAreaID)
              @a.ProjectAreaName
        }
```

I think the code should be something like this. I have no problem with visualizing the ProjectAreaName, but I can't send data from the checked radiobutton to model.

This is the error:

> "Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'RadioButtonFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."

Answer (score 2):

Cast type from dynamical to actual.

```
@foreach (var a in ViewBag.allProjectAreas as List<-*here comes your model*-)
    {                     
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.ProjectAreaID, a.ProjectAreaID)
          @a.ProjectAreaName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It says that it cannot understand var . Be explicit in conversion

```
@foreach(CompleteYourModelName modelObject in ViewBag.allProjectAreas)
{
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelObject.ProjectAreaID.ToString(), a.ProjectAreaID)
          @a.ProjectAreaName
}
```

example

```
     @foreach (MVCDemo2.Models.Department dept in ViewBag.DepartmentList)
            {
                @Html.RadioButton("Department", dept.Id, dept.isSelected)
@dept.Name;
            }
```